# Monitor soundcard output in Windows 7 with .NET

Tags: .net, windows, audio, soundcard

Is there a library that I can use to monitor any sound output from my computer?  I'd like to trigger certain actions when different audio levels are reached.  I think it would have the same components as building a VU, I would just be doing other things rather than visually displaying the levels.  I don't want to play music, only monitor any sounds that my computer is making (I am assuming this is monitored through the soundcard, though I could be mistaken).

Is there a library for this?  I'm having a hell of a time finding anything.  I might just not know the right terms to search for.

I'm only specifying .NET because I assume it's the easiest to access low-level windows stuff.  If there's a way to do it with another language, I'm open to that possibility as well.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

The IAudioMeterInformation interface in Vista and up.  This is only easy to use in C++ code, there's no type library for the audio interfaces.  Maybe you can google somebody that already wrapped this.